# Testing External Accessory Framework app

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, external-accessory

is there a way to write sample code (or run the EADemo app) without iAP hardware?
As an example:
 - have the simulator emulate the hardware
 - using cheap a device of which I know the protocol string

I just need to write an app that detects the accessory and gets some informations. The EADemo app is fine, but I don't have any real or emulated hardware.

Any hint?

Thank you

P.S.
i am not part of the MFi program, right now

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to test with simulator or any other device except with MFi device.To communicate with an external device using dock connector or bluetooth(bluetooth classic) you require MFi.You can try to get a MFi device from existing vendors like Bluegiga.

Comment: Can i make tests using existing hardware like the Apple Camera Connector or something similar? If so how can get the protocol name to use?

Comment: Could you tell me what you want to achieve so that I ll try to help you

Comment: in the short run I just need to run the EADemo app with real hardware in order to make it work for a demonstration. In he long run I need to connect via bluetooth to a device (non MFi) using SPP/RFCOMM. Because this is an explorative effort for an eventual future product we cannot sustain the effort to became part of the Mfi right now.

Comment: I don't think you can do this(You can't even get SPP).You can use Corebluetooth if your device supports BLE.You can try private framework like BluetoothManager.App may not be accepted in  appstore.

Comment: I cannot use BLE and I tried BluetoothManager private API. With the latter I've been able to pair the remote device but not to exchange data. Another option could be a RedPark serial cable (that is MFi) and a RS232 bluetooth extender...